Making a Python executable for Linux virtual machine
I'm writing a short program and I need to deploy it to Google Cloud Linux VM but my machine is Windows.
I read that PyInstaller is cross-platform but the executable needs to be made from a Linux machine to run on Linux. I tried installing it on a GCP VM but got this error when I tried pip install:
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

I also tried sudo apt install, but that also doesn't work:
$ sudo apt install python3-pyinstaller
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pyinstaller
enter code here

Is there any way for me to install pyinstaller on a GCP VM instance? Or is there a better way to build this executable for Linux?
